# WebView no muestra pdf xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo un backend publicado el cual me muestra un pdf en un endpoint :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto funciona bien pero a la hora de querer mostrar eso en un webview xamarin forms no carga nada, se queda en blanco. Este es el XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
                        <Button Text="nothing"></Button>
                        <WebView 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HeightRequest="300"
                        WidthRequest="300"

                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Source="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">

                        </WebView>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Probaste abrir el enlace en el explorar del teléfono y no del webview que le deben faltar librerías como por ejemplo para leer el pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Proba abrir el explorar externo de la app.

```
    using Xamarin.Essentials;

private void AbrirExplorador()
{
    Browser.OpenAsync("Uri");
}
```

o puedes pasarle mas parametros si es necesario.

```
private void AbrirExplorador()
{
    await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, new BrowserLaunchOptions
                    {
                        LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred,
                        TitleMode = BrowserTitleMode.Show,
                        PreferredToolbarColor = Color.AliceBlue,
                        PreferredControlColor = Color.Violet
                    });
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Comment: Hola así si funciona.Pero la idea no es sacar al usuario de la app. Por eso es que necesito que sea en el webview porque apartenecesito mostrar otros controles en esa ventana.

Comment: Quizas con un custom renderer tengas mas control sobre el webview, nunca intente ver un pdf desde webview. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview?view=xamarin-forms